# CS Cart duplicate controller index page bug

Tags: cs-cart

We using CS Cart about 5 years already, never had a problems before. But yesterday we found a strange bug.

We noticed that probably only index not working. We redirected index to other page now.

We made print screen of index bug: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVDNM.jpg

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Hi, the screenshot is not working!

Answer (score 0):

Please rename the file `.../controllers/customer/index.php` to `.../controllers/customer/index.post.php` and will solve the error